# Spring Boot- set JmsTemplate Configuration Properties from Java class (not from application properties file)

Tags: java, spring-boot, jms, ibm-mq

Followed this tutorial https://developer.ibm.com/messaging/2018/04/03/mq-jms-spring-boot/ and developed a Spring Boot JMS applicatin which sends a message to IBM MQ. (used this dependency - `mq-jms-spring-boot-starter`).

As per the tutorial, the configuration properties (Queue Manager, Channel, Port etc) can be given in `application.yml`/ `application.properties` file as below, and `JmsTemplate` will automatically be configured with the properties.

```
ibm.mq.queueManager=QM1
ibm.mq.channel=SYSTEM.DEF.SVRCONN
ibm.mq.connName=server.example.com(1414)
ibm.mq.user=user1
ibm.mq.password=passw0rd
```

The application works perfect and it sends message to the MQ now this way.

But I want to set the properties inside the class, not from the properties file (reading from a database or something). How to set these values inside the class?

Comment: https://github.com/lzp4ever/IBM_WebSphere_MQ_Spring_Boot_JMS

Answer (score 2):

You can use a customizer method on the CF after the initial properties have been populated.

In the Application class, this code allows additional properties to be configured:

```
@Bean
public MQConnectionFactoryCustomizer myCustomizer() {

  MQConnectionFactoryCustomizer c = new MQConnectionFactoryCustomizer() {
    @Override
    public void customize(MQConnectionFactory factory) {
       factory.setXXXX(property, value);
    }
  };
  return c;

}
```

Comment: I use this to pass the `ibm.mq.user` and `ibm.mq.password` through `@Value` annotation to support SpEL expressions (that I used to call my secrets manager `ibm.mq.user=#{mySecretsManager.getSecret('my-mq-user')}` for some profiles and not others)